# How to ADD Table Row to the 2nd table exclusively without adding to the 1st table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'd like to ***exclusively*** add table rows to the 2nd table when the user input the row no and click the button. The problem is when the button is clicked, table rows are being added to both tables. I've tried to assign an id to the 2nd table and the code wont work. Any ideas?

```js
$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
  var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);

  if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
    alert('Please enter number of injection');
  } else {

    $tbody = $('table tbody');
    $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');
    var lastRowIndex=($row.index()==-1? 0:$row.index()) +1 ;
    additionalRows = new Array(numNewRows);
    for(i=0;i<numNewRows;i++)
    {
    additionalRows[i]=` <tr>
    <td>${lastRowIndex}</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="vaccineid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width:160px"name="vaccinename1[]">       </td>
     </tr>`
      lastRowIndex=lastRowIndex+1;
    }
   
    $tbody.append(additionalRows.join());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Table 1<table id="zero">
  <tbody>
  
 <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="vaccineid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width:160px"name="vaccinename1[]"> 
       </tbody>
</table>
<input type="number" id="insert-rows-amnt" name="insert-rows-amnt" value="<?php echo $tam ?>" />
<button id="add-row" type="button">Rows no</button>

<table id="one">
  <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you've set an id to each `table`.

I'm just selecting the second table by the id

```
$tbody = $('table#one tbody');
```

And that is working:

```js
$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
  var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);

  if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
    alert('Please enter number of injection');
  } else {

    $tbody = $('table#one tbody');
    $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');
    var lastRowIndex=($row.index()==-1? 0:$row.index()) +1 ;
    additionalRows = new Array(numNewRows);
    for(i=0;i<numNewRows;i++)
    {
    additionalRows[i]=` <tr>
    <td>${lastRowIndex}</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="vaccineid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width:160px"name="vaccinename1[]">       </td>
     </tr>`
      lastRowIndex=lastRowIndex+1;
    }
   
    $tbody.append(additionalRows.join());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Table 1<table id="zero">
  <tbody>
  
 <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="vaccineid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width:160px"name="vaccinename1[]"> 
       </tbody>
</table>
<input type="number" id="insert-rows-amnt" name="insert-rows-amnt" value="<?php echo $tam ?>" />
<button id="add-row" type="button">Rows no</button>

<table id="one">
  <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you can mark my answer with the green tick if you think it resolved your problem. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You are adding rows to $tbody which is present in both tables. So to add row in table two append row in tbody of table 2 only

```
$tbody = $('table#one tbody ');
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/uc3nfdjw/